# What does "Length of label vector does not match # of instances." sentence mean in GA of Matlab? What should I do?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, libsvm, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I'm using Genetic Algorithm & because my dataset is a little bad, It does not converge to the minimum & I receive this error:

(***Note: Before the error, I see this comment on command window:
Length of label vector does not match # of instances.

***Note:
When I run it for linear kernel function in SVM it's OK. but when I run it for RBF,Polynomial,Sigmoid kernel function, it happens.)

Matlab System Error:

> Matlab has encountered an internal problem and needs to close.

my code is like this:

```
(GA part):
    x = ga(@(nu) nu_svm_rbf( nu,train_classset,train_dataset,test_classset,test_dataset ),1,[],[],[],[],lb,ub);
    nu_optimum_svd_rbf(1,i) = x;
```

What should I do by this sentence:
Length of label vector does not match # of instances.
What does it mean? it occurs before running the GA.
Would you please help me?
Thanks

Note: I'm using libSVM & my dataset size is 1000 points with 10 features.

Comment: How large are your data sets? It's unclear to me what you're using to evaluate the SVM, but if you're using an external package like libsvm, this may be because of an error with that package rather than MATLAB itself. I've had this error in the past using libsvm when I exceeded some internal memory constraints.

Comment: Is the Google Analytics tag intentional ?

Comment: I'm using libSVM & my dataset size is 1000 points with 10 features.

Comment: Does it mean that my memory is low? It's RAM size is 8 GB. should I use another computer with RAM 16 GB? or I should use super computer? What is the solution? what is your idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `options` argument.

You probably want `gaoptimset('Generations', 1000)`

Comment: but it says this sentence: "Length of label vector does not match # of instances." before running. What does it mean? what should I do?

Comment: I have tested it. the problem is that it don't enter to the GA at all for RBF,Polynomial & Sigmoid kernel function of SVM. (it works for linear kernel function).